# Redirect all pages to new domain exclude one page with htacces

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I try redirect all pages to new domain exclude one page with htacces.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}!^/onepage.php/
RewriteRule (.*) http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This is working but page onepage.php show internal error 500

Comment: Ahev you tried addinf `$` at the end of `^/onepage.php$` ?

Comment: Why is there a slash page.php/ ?

Comment: Not working. This line is a problem. RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}!^/onepage.php$

Comment: Try removing slash end of like `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/onepage.php`.

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/onepage.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/onepage.php$ Not working

Comment: @BCM - Any other rules in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Only RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /adv.php?category=$1&product=$2 [L]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with either of the following in your `.htaccess` file:

**Example 1:** Check the request URI for `onepage.php` and redirect if it is not being requested:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/onepage.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Example 2:** If `onepage.php` is being requested, don't do anything. Otherwise, redirect:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^onepage\.php - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

As you're redirecting *everything* except for `onepage.php`, you do not need any other rules in your file. The rules above should be the only ones in there.