# Redirect old domain to new domain except one html file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to transfer old domain URL to new domain URL. For example:
In my old domain have 3 files, name is

> a.html,  b.php,  c.xml

now i want to redirect it into new domain using htaccess with out a.html file.
like

```
old.com -> new.com
old.com/b.php -> new.com/b.php
old.com/c.xml -> new.com/c.xml
# Note this will not to redirect new domain
old.com/a.html -> old.com/a.html
```

as per this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30029279/redirect-all-pages-to-new-domain-exclude-one-page-with-htacces)  I tried this following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule a\.html - [L]
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.new.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

and this Code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/a.html [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.new.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

But it redirects in to all the pages into the new domain including a.html file.
What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your rule looks ok. Did you clear your browser cache?

Comment: Actually i tried in incognito window and private window only @starkeen

Comment: Are both the htaccess and the html files located in your `/root` folder?

Comment: Yes @starkeen sorry for the late reply

Comment: Are there any other rules and in your HTC cess?